# If else login page in php

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have made a simple login page in html with a if else login script in php. The only problem i run into is how to add multiple users. When I do add another user it gives me both the Logged in statement and the "you have not requested a login form statement" I will put the code down below. Any help is appreciated.

```
  <?php

 $username = $_POST['reg_user'];
 $password = $_POST['pass'];

 //ctoney ctoney123
 if ($username =='ctoney' AND $password=='ctoney123') {
    echo "You have logged in!";
}
 if ($username =='croney' AND $password=='ctoney123') {
    echo "you have logged in!";

 else {
    echo "You have not requested a login form!";
} 
?>
```

Comment: if you gonna have multiple users, consider using a database to store username-password pairs. Then query your table for proper login info.

Comment: don't pass $_POST/$_GET variables directly onto your query strings! you're susceptible of a sql injection! sanitize your input first!!!

Comment: It looks pretty clear that he isn't using a database, which means; he's pretty safe from all sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use else if statement

Check out http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-QF3Wb/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

```
<?php

 $username = $_POST['reg_user'];
 $password = $_POST['pass'];

 //ctoney ctoney123
 if ($username =='ctoney' AND $password=='ctoney123') {
    echo "You have logged in!";
} else if ($username =='croney' AND $password=='ctoney123') {
    echo "you have logged in!";
} else {
    echo "You have not requested a login form!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks seemed to be the fix.

Comment: @JozefDúc I think he's making his first step in programming. It's motivating to begin with a working script and improve it through time then waiting until we learned everything to start developping something

Comment: @Isaac I agree with you, but I think it is better to learn in proper way at the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're gonna do it like that you can make it a little more boring and complex to manage. like

```
<?php
if ($username == 'croney' && $password == 'ctoney123' || $username == "user2" && $password == "password2" || $username == "user3" && $password == "password 3"){
echo "Logged In successfully";
} else {
echo "You have not logged into my awkward management system";
}
?>
```